# Set start date min value to end date minus 90 days

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik, raddatepicker

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                debugger;
                var startDate = $find('<%= RdpStartDate.ClientID %>');
                var endDate = $find('<%= RdpEndDate.ClientID %>');
                var end = endDate.get_selectedDate();
                var start = startDate.get_selectedDate();
                startDate.set_minDate(end-90);
              
                });
```

I'm trying to set start date min value to less than 90 days of end date all before that disabled but this isn't working, help please.

Comment: Can you please update your question and explain what exactly you're trying to do with the date?

Comment: I wat to set my startdate min date to 90 days less than the selected end date

Answer (score 0):

Try to do change the code to the following:

```
end.setDate(end.getDate() - 90);
startDate.set_minDate(end);
```

Update:

```
const endNinety = new Date();
endNinety.setDate(end.getDate())
endNinety.setDate(endNinety.getDate() - 90);
startDate.set_minDate(endNinety);
```

Comment: I did still it's not working

Comment: Try the edited code @sanmeet-singh.

Comment: Try the updated code @sanmeet-singh.